# Explode string with coordinates to lat/lon in MySQL

Tags: mysql, split, coordinates

In my database i have this string for a coordinate:
N52.27337 E4.98162

Now i will split this into two field with **lat** and **lon**.

I figured out that i can use SUBSTRING_INDEX to split it. But how can i update this in two fields with a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the string for a coordinate: N52.27337 E4.98162 is stored in column myColumn

```
substr(mycolumn, 1, locate(' ',mycolumn) -1) /* lat N52.27337 */
substr(mycolumn,locate(' ',mycolumn)+1, 100) /* E4.98162 ... 
                      100 is for get all the char after starting position */
```

then you could update your table using eg: columns names lat and lng as  string with N52.27337 and E4.98162

```
Update my_table 
set lat =  substr(mycolumn, 1, locate(' ',mycolumn) -1),
  lng = substr(mycolumn,locate(' ',mycolumn)+1, 100)
```

you can obatin the values without N and E using  and store in decimal column  (using automatic casting)

```
Update my_table 
set lat = right(substr(mycolumn, 1, locate(' ',mycolumn) -1) , 
             length(substr(mycolumn, 1, locate(' ',mycolumn) -1)) -1),

    lng = right(substr(my_column, locate(' ',my_column)+1, 100), 
              length(substr(my_column, locate(' ',my_column)+1, 100))-1)
```

Comment: And how can i strip the E and N?

Comment: Your lat, lng are always in North  East .. area??

Comment: This coordinates are used in Europe. I want to split them over two fields.

Comment: then you never have S W ..  ok ?

Comment: That's correct. I have only N (lat) en E (long)....... If I am not mistaken and I put them in the right order ;-)

Comment: answer  updated  ..then you can use right for the string  length -1  ..

Comment: I've tried it, and the lat-field is correct

but the 'lng'-field has the last two characters of the coordinates-string. Whats wrong in the last update query?

Comment: Done, and thanx!